# Cuda iterative program stopping unusually. Runs only when PC is restarted Each time

Tags: cuda, iteration

I have a iterative cuda program which iterates new values as required.
It is a confidential code so I cant share, but I want to discuss the problem.

The iterative program runs properly on my PC when I work with less data.
I have proper allocation and deallocation codes.

No matter how many times I run the program it runs properly with less data.

But in case of huge data, It runs properly one time but not multiple times providing an error "****.exe has stopped working.....".
Same error persists until I restart the PC...each time.
It is not feasible to restart the PC each time for me to start the program. So What might be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a memory error.

You should try running `cuda-memcheck`, this will make obvious any memory errors.

Other options include using [error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) within your code, this would catch the problems as they arise.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You can't have `cuda-memcheck` _in_ your program. You can _run_ your program with `cuda-memcheck my_program`. Have you tried the error handling I suggested? You essentially need to put it around every cuda runtime api and kernel call in your code. It will definitely alert you to the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I am sorry about the last comment, I have properly used cudaFreeHost, cudaFreee in my program. I make proper use of CudaSafeCall. Memory error is less likely. The problem as I said is, crashing for second run (not the 1st run) on large set of data.for small sets of data, it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a tricky one. I would guess it to be a pointer error. Unfortunately it is not really something you can get help for here. My only suggestion is a careful diagnosis of which size data set will cause the problem and some thorough testing of your implementation. Good luck.